# Is there a man page for PROMPT in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

I know how to look up commands with the `man` command.  When looking at other people's .zshrc files, I see what I think are builtin variables (`PROMPT`, `RPROMPT`, etc.). Where might I learn more about these? I'm running MacOSX Lion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering directly to your question title:

Yes, there is: The prompt variables are listed in the *PARAMETERS USED BY THE SHELL* section of `man zshparam`.

The prompt escape sequences are explained in the *SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES* section of `man zshmisc`.

If you don't know in which man page you find the desired information, you can use `man zshall`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few online references to resources regarding zsh and prompts:

- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_14.html
- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Prompts